# Clarification of some Ubuntu commands

Tags: apt, repository, dpkg

So just wondered what happens when I run these commands (specifically on Ubuntu):

```
# Add NVIDIA package repositories
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1804_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1804_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update

# Install NVIDIA driver
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nvidia-driver-418
# Reboot. Check that GPUs are visible using the command: nvidia-smi

# Install development and runtime libraries (~4GB)
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends \
    cuda-10-1 \
    libcudnn7=7.6.4.38-1+cuda10.1  \
    libcudnn7-dev=7.6.4.38-1+cuda10.1
```

These are instructions of installing CUDA for Ubuntu, so I have basic understanding of what they do, but commands are unclear to me (apart from `wget`). What is `dpkg`, what is `apt-key adv --fetch-keys`, why we don't add a key from the second repo, but only from the first one, why do we run `sudo dpkg -i` for the first `.deb` file and `sudo apt install` for the second?

It's a general question and has no connection to CUDA specifically, I just want to know more about Linux.

Thanks!

Comment: In general, if you open a terminal and do `man dpkg` you will see an explanation of what dpkg is.

Answer (score 1):

This command download .deb package with CUDA repository information

> wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb

`dpkg` is package manager for Debian. Option -i will install previously downloaded package

> sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb

`apt-key` is APT key management utility. `adv` command pass advanced options to gpg.

> sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub

.

> why do we run sudo dpkg -i for the first .deb file and sudo apt install for the second?

`apt` is frontend for dpkg. It could resolve dependencies, download and install required package.
Probably first .deb file has no dependencies, while second one has.

> why we don't add a key from the second repo, but only from the first one

Because they have the same public key

Comment: Thanks! By the way, when we use `dpkg` and `apt install` here, they don’t install packages, they just add them somewhere. As far as I understand, everything is installed in the last line, that is `apt-get install`, isn’t it?

Comment: @Denisof actually they do.  Command  sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb install package that contain apt source list for cuda repository

Answer (score 0):

> why we don't add a key from the second repo, but only from the first one

Because they have the same public key.

```
curl http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
curl https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
```

> why do we run sudo dpkg -i for the first .deb file and sudo apt install for the second?

**In this case** `dpkg` and `apt` will setup only a repository, `apt` have the same effect as `dpkg`, because the repository setup doesn't require some other dependency to be installed.

Please note that `apt` is able to solve the dependencies , but `dpkg` doesn't.